# Flask-WTF CSRF token error when on Docker

Tags: docker, flask, csrf, flask-wtforms

After submitting a Flask-WTF form, I see the errors "Session token is missing" or "The CSRF tokens do not match". The errors only occur when running on Docker with Docker-compose i.e. there is no CSRF error when I'm running the Flask app normally. I'm using Flask-WTF 0.14.2, Docker 17.03.1-ce, Docker-compose 1.13.0-rc1

Answer (score 2):

Chances are this is because you're using Docker Machine, and your `SERVER_NAME` is set to `192.168.99.100` (or whatever your default Docker Machine IP is).

I've noticed that most webkit based browsers don't set cookies for IP based domains, but they allow `localhost`.

One option you could do is:

- Edit your `/etc/hosts` file by adding: `192.168.99.100 local.docker` (replacing that IP with your Docker Machine IP address if it's different).
- Change your `SERVER_NAME` to use `local.docker`.

If you want to see a full write up about this, I blogged about it a while back at https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/fix-missing-csrf-token-issues-with-flask.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm building the app just with docker-compose, no docker-machine.

Comment: on Ubuntu 16.04